# Axios call to controller generates 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: laravel, axios, vuex

I am trying to implement a register function in my controller but when I the tryRegister action the browser logs a 500 (Internal Server Error). So I removed everything from the register function and just tried to return a simple string as response. And the strange thing was that it still generates that error. So since the login was already working I tried to do a message response in the login function and call it with the tryLogin action, but the crazy thing is that the login function responds just fine and logges "login"? What am I doing wrong? Does it have anything to do with the request parameter? Because that is the only difference between the two functions.

Also I'm new to back-end development, and I'm really trying to grasp this.

Vuex actions

```
import axios from "axios";

export default {
    tryRegister(context, credentials) {
        context.commit("login");
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            axios
                .post("/api/auth/register", credentials)
                .then(response => {
                    console.log(response.data);
                    context.commit("loginSucces", response.data);
                    resolve(response.data);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error.response);
                    reject(error);
                });
        });
    },
    tryLogin(context, credentials) {
        context.commit("login");
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            axios
                .post("/api/auth/login", credentials)
                .then(response => {
                    console.log(response.data);
                    context.commit("loginSucces", response.data);
                    resolve(response.data);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    context.commit("loginFailed", error);
                    reject(error);
                });
        });
    },
    tryLogout(context) {
        context.commit("logout");
    }
};
```

Routes

```
<?php

Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'auth'

], function () {
    Route::post('register', 'AuthController@register');
    Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login');
    Route::post('logout', 'AuthController@logout');
    Route::post('refresh', 'AuthController@refresh');
    Route::post('me', 'AuthController@me');
});
```

Authorization Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new AuthController instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['login', 'register']]);
    }

    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        // $user = User::create([
        //     'email'    => $request->email,
        //     'password' => $request->password,
        // ]);

        // $token = auth('api')->login($user);

        // return $this->respondWithToken($token);
        return "register";
    }

    /**
     * Get a JWT via given credentials.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function login()
    {
        // $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);

        // if (!$token = auth('api')->attempt($credentials)) {
        //     return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
        // }

        // return $this->respondWithToken($token);
        return "login";
    }

    /**
     * Get the authenticated User.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function me()
    {
        return response()->json(auth('api')->user());
    }

    /**
     * Log the user out (Invalidate the token).
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function logout()
    {
        auth('api')->logout();

        return response()->json(['message' => 'Successfully logged out']);
    }

    /**
     * Refresh a token.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function refresh()
    {
        return $this->respondWithToken(auth('api')->refresh());
    }

    /**
     * Get the token array structure.
     *
     * @param  string $token
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    protected function respondWithToken($token)
    {
        return response()->json([
            'access_token' => $token,
            'user' => $this->guard()->user(),
            'token_type' => 'bearer',
            'expires_in' => auth('api')->factory()->getTTL() * 60
        ]);
    }

    public function guard()
    {
        return Auth::Guard('api');
    }
}
```

Comment: When you're working with the backend, 500 internal server error is just Javascript telling you there's an error, to figure out what the error actually is, go to the network tab on your browser and click preview on the red highlighted request

Comment: @CaddyDZ aaah okay thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing to import the `Request class`.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```